# Перерисовка OpenGL сильно тормозит, когда объекты загораживают друг друга

Tags: opengl

Как избавиться от тормозов при перерисовки объектов друг на друге? Стоит только нарисовать несколько тысяч полигонов друг на друге или почти вплотную - мгновенно падает производительность, если на них посмотреть. Как это исправить? Задача такова, что полигоны должны многократно пересекаться между собой.

Comment: Почему не действует функция discard в шейдере? По идеи она должна отбрасывать всё ненужное. Но даже при абсолютно чёрном экране fps падает в разы, хотя ничего не ресуется.

Comment: Если речь о пиксельном шейдере, то суть в том, чтобы даже не выполнять его для пикселов, которые не видны. Нужно стараться по возможности минимизировать количество таких пикселов. До всяких discard-ов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый известный способ - это сортировка полигонов. Ускорение при этом получается за счёт того, что при промахе теста глубины не требуется вычисление цвета пикселя.

Второй метод - совершенствование методов теста видимости полигонов.

Ну и конечно, стараться засунуть массивы вершин разом вместо множественного вызова glVertexXX